Understanding of Rudin Definitions 9.6c: $|A \mathbf{x}| \le \lambda|\mathbf{x}|$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \Bbb{R}^{n}$ $\implies$ $\|A\| \le \lambda$

Let $A$ be a linear transformation of $\Bbb{R}^n$  into  $\Bbb{R}^m$.
Define the norm $\|A\|$ of
$A$ to be the sup of all numbers $|A \mathbf{x}|$, where $\mathbf{x}$
ranges over all vectors in $ \Bbb{R}^{n}$ with  $|\mathbf{x}| \le 1$.
Observe
that the inequality $$ |A \mathbf{x}| \le\|A\||\mathbf{x}| $$ holds
for all $\mathbf{x} \in \Bbb{R}^{n}$. Also, if $\lambda$ is such that $|A
\mathbf{x}| \le \lambda|\mathbf{x}|$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \Bbb{R}^{n}$,
then $\|A\| \le \lambda$.

My understanding is as follows:
For every nonzero $\mathbf{x} \in \Bbb{R}^n $,  $|\frac{\mathbf{x}}{|\mathbf{x}|}|=1$, then $$|A(\frac{\mathbf{x}}{|\mathbf{x}|})|= |\frac{A\mathbf{x}}{|\mathbf{x}|}| = \frac{|A\mathbf{x}|}{|\mathbf{x}|} \le \|A\|$$ by the definition of $\|A\|$ and the linearity of $A$.
Suppose $0<s<\|A\|$, then there exists a nonzero $\mathbf{y} \in \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $|\mathbf{y}|\le1$ and $|A\mathbf{y}|> s \ge |\mathbf{y}|s $, that is $$\frac{|A\mathbf{y}|}{|\mathbf{y}|} > s$$
It follows that $$ \sup_{\mathbf{x} \in \Bbb{R}^n, \mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{0}}{\frac{|A\mathbf{x}|}{|\mathbf{x}|}}=\|A\|$$
If $\lambda$ is such that $|A\mathbf{x}| \le \lambda|\mathbf{x}|$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \Bbb{R}^{n}$, that is, $\frac{|A\mathbf{x}|}{|\mathbf{x}|} \le \lambda $ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \Bbb{R}^{n}$ and $\mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{0}$.
Hence, we can conclude that $\|A\| \le \lambda$.
Is my proof clear enough, or miss something ?

Unnecessarily complicated. If $|x|\le 1$ then $|Ax|\le \lambda$. Just take sup over all such $x$ to finish.

A little complement: Yes, and you have nearly established the following fact:
The following three non-negative real numbers are equal, and are therefore all equivalent definitions of $\|A\|$:
\begin{align*}
&\sup\{\|Ax\|:\, x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\, \|x\|\le 1  \}\\
=& \sup\{\|Ax\|:\, x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\, \|x\|=1\}\\
=& \sup\{\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}:\, x\in\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}\}.
\end{align*}
To see the second and third amount are equal, note that if $\|x\|=1$, then $\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}=\|Ax\|$,
and $\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$ only depends on "direction of $x$", i.e. if $x=\mu y$ ($\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, $x,y\ne 0$),
then $\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}=\frac{\|Ay\|}{\|y\|}$.
Therefore the sets $\{\|Ax\|:\, x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\, \|x\|=1\}$ and $\{\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}:\, x\in\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}\}$ are actually equal, and have the same sup.
To see $\sup\overbrace{\{\|Ax\|:\, x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\, \|x\|\le 1  \}}^{S}= \sup\overbrace{\{\|Ax\|:\, x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\, \|x\|=1\}}^{T}$,
note that $\sup S\ge \sup T$ is immediate since $S\supseteq T$.
Conversely, say $\|x\|\le 1$. If $x=0$ then $\|Ax\|=0\le \sup T$.
If $x\ne 0$ then $\|Ax\|\le \overbrace{\|A(\frac{x}{\|x\|}) \|}^{\in T}\le \sup T$.
We therefore conclude $\sup S=\sup T$.
